# Flutter snapshot.data!.docs[index]['xxx'] - data get

Tags: flutter

Im trying to find a way to fetch some single data from firestore into my app

Now i tried to get single data by:

```
final age = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['age'];
```

But i want to assign firestore docs into firebase account. The problem is that i can't put uid into "snapshot.data!.docs[`here`]['age]" cuz it is a int type.

I also tried this:

```
final uid = int.parse(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
final age = snapshot.data!.docs[uid]['age'];
```

but then i've got an error

```
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
LWlLyRy48gOv00NBPdYXuCv9F4g1
^
```

here is a part of code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final uid = int.parse(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
              final age = snapshot.data!.docs[uid]['age'];

              return Form(
```

Comment: Firebase UIDs, are not numbers. They are a combination of numeric and letter characters.

Comment: That's why I wrote that I want to find a way to do this. Even if it's a different way

Comment: Well if you need an int, you won't get it from a uid. your int.parse() line will always fail if you pass a user's uid. Can you provide more context into your firestore structure and why you need to use a UID there?

Comment: I need a UID because each document in the firestore is for a different user, so I want to assign a specific document to a specific account. To be able to get specific and needed information. I am unfamiliar with it, so if it is impossible or there is some other way, I will be glad to know

Comment: This is fine, but it doesn't have to be an int value. You can make the doc Id's a string value and set them to the UID. No need to place an int value. use something like follows for setting the ID: ...doc(UIDHere).set({value1: value, value2: value, etc.})

Comment: Could you specify how it should looks like? Because I don't quite understand it

Comment: I'd suggest going through the documentation. They do a good job of showing you project setup, how to read, write, query, etc. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents

Comment: Okay, I'll check. Thanks for your help :D